# Python 3 : How to get work day between range of two dates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on an implementation to get working day (exlcuding Saturday and Sunday). I wrote this code, it works properly but is there a better implementation?
Here is the code :

```
    def _get_open_dates(self, yesterday, i):
        count = 1
        dates = [yesterday]
        date = yesterday
        while count <= i:
            date = date - relativedelta(days=1)
            if not date.strftime("%w") in ('0', '6'):
                count += 1
                dates.append(date)
        return dates
```

yesterday is an object of type datetime.date(), the parameter i is an integer (number of date to get from yesterday).
PS : the return may contain dates between years and dates bewteen months.

Comment: This might be more suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com. That said, please revisit [ask] and the [tour]. Asking for "better" without any criteria is asking for opinions, which would make it off-topic here. Asking for suggestions to improve would be on-topic for a code review though!

Answer (score 2):

- Object of `datetime` class, has function called **weekday()**.
- It provides an integer in the range [0, 6]. Days 5 and 6 (weekend) can be easily skipped using a delta `days = 2`.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def _get_open_dates(day, i):
    dates = []
    for d in range(i+1):
        if 0 <= day.weekday() <= 4:
            dates.append(day)
            day += timedelta(days=1)
        else:
            day += timedelta(days=2)
    return dates

print(_get_open_dates(datetime.now(), 8))
```

**Output:**
Today being Friday (my time), get 8 weekdays.

```
[
datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 4, 13, 23, 35, 821911), 
datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 7, 13, 23, 35, 821911), 
datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 8, 13, 23, 35, 821911), 
datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 9, 13, 23, 35, 821911), 
datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 10, 13, 23, 35, 821911), 
datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 11, 13, 23, 35, 821911), 
datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 14, 13, 23, 35, 821911)
]
```

Comment: I think this will only work for a single week, and not for, say, one or two months, right?

Comment: Doesn't give the expected answer

Comment: true, yeah fixed my answer. i thought you wanted only days from active week.

Comment: thanks for your solution, I may gain some performance.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to do it with a list comprehension:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def _get_open_dates(start_day, i):
    return [start_day + timedelta(days=d) for d in range(i) if (start_day + timedelta(days=d)).weekday() <= 4]
```